# Undefined index after session logout

Tags: php

First, let me start by saying I've checked all over, there is really no exactly similar solution to my question already.
I am trying to make a header that displays certain user data when a user is logged in and display a login link or register when a user is not logged in. But what I get is that it works well when the user is logged in but on logout, it gives me an undefined index.

```
<?php

    if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){
        $user = $_SESSION['email_of_user'];
        $st=$conn->prepare("select * from membership where email= ? ");
        $st->bind_param("s", $user);
        $st->execute();
        $rs=$st->get_result();

     while($row=$rs->fetch_assoc()){ 

            echo '<div id="yourBtn" style="border: 1px solid black; cursor:pointer;display:block;width:50px;height:50px;border-radius:105px;align:left"><div style="position:relative;display:block;width:200px"><img src="./users/profile/'.$row["profile_pic"].'" width="50px" height="50px" alt="'.$row["name"].'" style="display:block;border-radius:105px"/></div></div>
                <div class="info">
                <span class="value">Welcome back, '.$row['name'].'!</span>
                <a href="../users/login-home.php">Go Shopping</a>
                </div>  
                <div class="options">
                <p><a href="../users/access-controlled.php">View Dashboard</a></p>
                <a href="../users/update-profile.php">Update your profile information</a>
                <p><a href="../users/logout.php">Logout</a></p>
                </div>';}

    }else{
            echo '<a href="/users/login.php">Login or Register</a>';}
        ?>
```

That is my code above. On logout, it says that $user is undefined but it works fine after login.

Another thing I noticed is that when I used session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE without the prepare  and while statements, it still does not display the else statement. Does it mean the session is not destroying properly after logout? Is my logout script(shown below) not properly destroyed?

```
 function LogOut()
{

    $sessionvar = $this->GetLoginSessionVar();

    $_SESSION[$sessionvar]=NULL;

    session_destroy();

    unset($_SESSION[$sessionvar]);

    session_write_close();

}
```

How do I fix this please? Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: What a returned value from `$this->GetLoginSessionVar()` ?

Comment: You can change while statement with if statement like this `if($rs && $rs->num_rows > 0) `

Comment: On logout function its enought with `session_destroy();`

Comment: you have already destroyed all the session , using `session_destroy();` function.

Comment: MR. A, tried your suggestion. It still returns the same error. The entire prepare bind while statement is within the if condition. I want it to be totally ignored when the else condition is true.